# How does one run a blink LED program on Google-Coral dev board mini and what IDE is recommended?

Tags: python, google-coral

I recently came across the Google Coral dev board mini in search of a ML microcontroller platform for a robotics and speech recognition project. I realized that there are minimal tutorials on creating projects from scratch for the dev board mini but a ton of example projects. The problem with these example projects is that it gets imported through a git clone through the Mendel linux terminal, which doesn't really tell me how to create my own project and where to compile and code it. To make things more clear I will use the ESP32 dev board as an example:

To write a program (C++) on a ESP32 dev board that controls the I/O pins, I used *PlatfromIO* to compile and flash the microcontroller. What IDE can be used to perform the same functionality on the Google-Coral dev board mini? Does there exist an article about this?

Sorry if my question seems obvious, but I feel that I spent too much time searching for the solution. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Coral dev board mini is a single board computer running a full Linux operating system, whereas the ESP32 is a *microcontroller* which does not run an OS, it is only flashed with a single C++ program. The difference is the same as a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino. Since the Coral dev board has a full OS, you can plug a monitor, mouse, and keyboard into it and develop code directly on it. Or you can use your PC to ssh into the coral board to copy files over and remotely run commands. Through these ways you can use any IDE you want.